# torch.matmul calculation not exact in Python

Tags: python, pytorch, matrix-multiplication

I encountered an astonishing problem. For a neural network, I multiply two matrices with `matrixA.matmul(MatrixB)`. matrixA is of size 8x648 (8 Batches) and matrixB of 648x600. Although every batch is identical (which is to say that each row of matrixA is identical) the seventh and eighth row of the output matrix differ from the other six. Despite the fact that they only differ slightly, this has an immense impact on the results of my network. Now I wonder how this can be. Stunningly, the problem doesn't occur, if I calculate `matrixA[0].matmul(matrixB)` and `matrixA[7].matmul(matrixB)` seperately.
Does anybody know why?

Comment: If a slight variation in a number has immense impact then you have an unstable system and it probably needs work. The differences you're seeing likely have to do with how matrix multiplication is optimized for performance, which usually admits some tolerance on precision.

Comment: well, maybe 'slightly' was a little bit exaggerated: the difference is around -3.8860e+01, -1.5192e+00, -1.3791e+01, -3.7310e-01, -2.0617e+01,....

Comment: What are the range of values in matrixA and matrixB?

Comment: Difference is too much, -3.8e+01??? Can you show some example matrices and how you calculate the difference?

Comment: It depends on the range of values. If matrixA and matrixB contain values like 1e100 then such errors would be expected.

Comment: I'll look into it, thank you. (I think the range is about 4000)

Comment: @jodag I guess you are right, I did not think about high values at first place.